# Definition of implicit environment value in example play-silhouette template (using Guice)

Tags: scala, authentication, guice, playframework-2.3

In the silhouette implementation example found [here](https://github.com/sne11ius/play-silhouette-slick-seed), how in the template is the implicit 'env' value (of type Environment[User, CachedCookieAuthenticator])  used in line 28 of /app/controllers/SignUpController.scala, for example, defined using Guice?

I guess I do not understand how provideEnvironment in app/utils/di/SilhouetteModule.scala is used to "inject" the Silhouette Enviroment into SignUpController (for example) via the "injector" created in line 24 of app/Global.scala. I don't see provideEnvironment being used anywhere in the play-silhouette-slick-seed example, so I can't seem to figure out what values are given to its arguments (such as userService, authenticatorService etc).

Answer (score 2):

This example of silhouette module use Guice for scala Dependency Injection framework. All bindings are configured in `util.di.SilhouetteModule.scala` file. There is another example where Dependency Injection is replaced by Cake pattern. [look at this](https://github.com/yzernik/silhouette-cake-seed)

[edited]In short:

If you look at the `Global.scala` file, you'll find the guice configuration. Guice is forced to create every controller. Every view is dependend on controllers and will be managed by guice too.

The `SilhouetteModule.scala` file, as was mentioned above, is for configuration Silhouette module. There are few methods annotated with `@Provides`. If you look at the [Guice documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods). Such method is called by Guice every time it needs class type the method returns, for instance: each time guice need to inject `Environment[User, CachedCookieAuthenticator]` it call `def provideEnvironment` method because this method return such type.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I was looking for a better understanding of how the Environment is setup/defined using Guice (I have edited the title to reflect this). As indicated in the 2nd paragraph above, I do know that SilhouetteModule is where this is done; however, I do not understand where provideEnvironment and the other provide<> statements are used (in addition to how the bindings come into play). I guess everything is set up by Guice under the hood, and I will need to go and check out the Guice documentation to get a clearer picture of the above.